# How can I set second element as rightmost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
div {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div> box1 </div>
<div> box2 </div>
```

All I want to do is changing the place of `box1` with `box2`. I mean I want to put `box2` as the rightmost one. How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I don't want to use `flex` and `order` properties.

Comment: Add class to box2 as:
`<div class="box2">box 2</div>`

Now Using css do:
`div.box2{
  float:right;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a container like below:

```css
.container{
    float:right;
}
.container div {
    float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div> box1 </div>
<div> box2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, I cannot add a *container* to my HTML.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to achieve without wrapping it into another div. You need to change the order of divs in HTML if you still prefer.

Comment: @MartinAJ why cant you wrap your divs in another div?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Because I need this view for `@media (max-width: 1150px){`, before that I want another view. That's why I cannot change the HTML.

Comment: @MartinAJ where on earth did you say that in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I had to mention it.

Comment: @MartinAJ Also you never mentioned that you "cant" change the html. How can it be you cant change the html and but you can change your css.  It dont make much sence. Please in the future make you that you include all relevant information in your question before posting it

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change your `HTML` and you are willing to do it with pure CSS then you have very limited control over position of elements.

If your boxes are not more than two and have fixed or (possibly small) width then here is a small trick that might help you.

Use CSS3 `translate()` to swap the position of your elements:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div> box1 </div>
<div> box2 </div>
```

Comment: Yes it works .. but if I want to use `transform` property, I can simply use `flex` property instead and set an `order` to second element. But you know, the most of my website's users use old browsers. That's why I'm trying to avoid using CSS3 properties.

Comment: @MartinAJ You can use vendor prefixes. `transorm` property has support in IE9+ browsers.

Comment: Alright .. thank you, upvote. Just can you please add `-webkit-`, `-ms-`, `-moz-` codes to your answer?

Comment: I think that make sense, if you can use Jquery you should be able to user css properties..

Answer (score 0):

```
change the display of div to inline-block, those box will in the same line

div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div> box2 </div>
<div> box1 </div>
```

Otherwise you need to use flex and order or javascript. 
$('#secondDiv').insertBefore('#firstDiv');

Comment: Hah ..! really?! Thank you for your attempt. But I clearly mentioned in the question I want to *"put the **second** element as rightmost one"*. In your case, `box1` is second one and should be as rightmost one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style on Div incase you cannot add classes, into your css.

```
 <div> box1 </div>
    <div style="float:right; right:0"> box2 </div>
```

Comment: shift order,    <div style="float:right; right:0"> box2 </div>
<div> box1 </div>

Comment: hmm, do you have access to jquery there?